# R Random Forest Model: Issue with Generating Confusion Matrix

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest

When I can trying to generate a confusion matrix for my random forest model I am getting the following error: Error in !all.equal(nrow(data), ncol(data)) : invalid argument type

Here is the code I used:

```
`ind <- sample(2, nrow(completeData), replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.7, 0.3))
trainData <- completeData[ind == 1, ]
testData <- completeData[ind == 2, ]

rf1 <- randomForest(price~., data = trainData)
print(rf1)

#Random Forest Model
p1 <- predict(rf1, newdata = testData)
testData$p1 <- p1

#Confusion matrix 
confusionMatrix(table(testData$price, testData$p1))`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`price` and, hence, `p1` are probably *continuous* data, whereas `confusionMatrix` works with *categorical* data (`factor`s).

You could `cut` your continuous data into categories and run the `confusionMatrix` like so (*adjust breaks according to actual price range*):

```
confusionMatrix(table(cut(testData$price, breaks = 0:10),
                      cut(testData$p1, breaks = 0:10)
                      )
                )
```

... but why downgrade the continuous data instead of inspecting on the continuous level (scatterplot, correlation etc.)?